# Optimize multi-join query, please

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, average

i made a query for sql but it's really heavy and i really don't see how i can optimize it, the explanations comes after :

```
SELECT tyds.user_tyd, 
       tyds.product_tyd, 
       tyds.action_tyd, 
       products.price_product, 
       data_8, 
       data_9, 
       avg_8, 
       sum_9 
FROM   tyds 
       INNER JOIN products 
               ON tyds.product_tyd = products.id_product 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT product_tyd, 
                          Avg(data_tyd) AS avg_8 
                   FROM   tyds 
                   WHERE  action_tyd = 8 
                   GROUP  BY product_tyd) Agg_1 
               ON Agg_1.product_tyd = tyds.product_tyd 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT product_tyd, 
                          Sum(data_tyd) AS sum_9 
                   FROM   tyds 
                   WHERE  action_tyd = 9 
                   GROUP  BY product_tyd) Agg_2 
               ON Agg_2.product_tyd = tyds.product_tyd 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT product_tyd, 
                          data_tyd AS data_8 
                   FROM   tyds 
                   WHERE  user_tyd = 3 
                          AND action_tyd = 8) Agg_3 
               ON Agg_3.product_tyd = tyds.product_tyd 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT product_tyd, 
                          data_tyd AS data_9 
                   FROM   tyds 
                   WHERE  user_tyd = 3 
                          AND action_tyd = 9) Agg_4 
               ON Agg_4.product_tyd = tyds.product_tyd 
WHERE  tyds.user_tyd = 3 
       AND tyds.action_tyd = 1 
GROUP  BY tyds.product_tyd
```

All this jointures because i need to get a lot of things :
I define an id_user in tyds.user_tyd = 3
tyds.action_tyd = 1 because i want to group by the tyds.product_tyd WHERE the previous id_user as an tyds.action_tyd = 1.

Then i want : 
-data_8 is the value of tyds.data_tyd WHERE user_tyd = 3 AND action_tyd = 8
-same for data_9

-for AVG and COUNT i want to skip the tyds.user_tyd condition and only group by id_product.

Actually, this query is working but i think it's really heavy and has too much SELECT...

I put a similar question a month ago but i had to review my architecture so i'm sorry...

Thanks a lot.

e1 : i use MySQL

Comment: Is it necessary to keep it in one query?

Comment: Well, it will be executed a lot of time so i think it's better. And i'll have some pages with 3 of this kinds...it doesn't look too slow  actually but i prefer thinking about optimiz. now.

Comment: Ok, I understand you. My proposition is to prepare a temporary table for each subquery in inner join. I'm sure it will be faster. If you don't want to do that, tell us which dbms do you use. Have you got indexes on tables?

Comment: That's seem interesting even if i don't know how you do that. I got indexes on every id_TABLE.

Comment: +1 to whomever formatted that sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need all of those joins and subqueries; you can eliminate most of them by moving logic from `WHERE`-clauses into the field-list, using [`CASE` expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case):

```
SELECT 3 AS user_tyd, tyds.product_tyd, 1 AS action_tyd,
       products.price_product,
       MAX(CASE WHEN user_tyd = 3 AND action_tyd = 8 THEN data_tyd END) data_8,
       MAX(CASE WHEN user_tyd = 3 AND action_tyd = 9 THEN data_tyd END) data_9,
       AVG(CASE WHEN action_tyd = 8 THEN data_tyd END) AS avg_8,
       SUM(CASE WHEN action_tyd = 9 THEN data_tyd END) AS sum_9
  FROM tyds
  JOIN products
    ON tyds.product_tyd = products.id_product
 WHERE tyds.product_tyd IN
         ( SELECT product_tyd
             FROM tyds
            WHERE tyds.user_tyd = 3
              AND tyds.action_tyd = 1
         )
 GROUP
    BY tyds.product_tyd
;
```

(Note: the `MAX(...)` in the third and fourth lines are just a way of forcing a non-null value to be preferred over a null one.)

You'll have to test to see if this is actually faster, but I'm betting that it is.

Comment: Yep it's ten time faster...thanks a lot. what's the point to define 3 AS user_tyd ?

Comment: @pierreaurelemartin: You're welcome! And, the point of `3 AS user_tyd` is to get the right value of `user_tyd`: I had to remove `tyds.user_tyd = 3` from the `WHERE` clause, because the calculation of `avg_8` and `sum_9` had to take into account other records, so using `tyds.user_tyd` in the field-list would give non-deterministic (i.e. wrong) results.

Comment: Ok, i don't really understand how everything is working but i'll decompose your query to get it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example,only for first Agg_%

```
create temporary table Agg_1
(
  product_tyd ...,
  avg_8 ...
)

insert into Agg_1
SELECT product_tyd, AVG(data_tyd) AS avg_8 FROM tyds WHERE action_tyd = 8 
GROUP BY product_ty

SELECT  tyds.user_tyd, tyds.product_tyd, tyds.action_tyd, products.price_product,
data_8, data_9, avg_8, sum_9 
FROM tyds 
INNER JOIN products 
ON tyds.product_tyd = products.id_product 
INNER JOIN Agg_1 ON Agg_1.product_tyd = tyds.product_tyd
...
```

Now,i see you are working on Mysql. I'm not sure it will work on MySql, i'm not MySql guru. But, I'm sure it work on oracle and sybase.

Comment: It works with mysql. I'll test that solution to compare with the other solutions.